# How to handle "Location Unknown"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Core Location Manager set up. Sometimes, when the phone is on 3G/4G signal it reports a `LocationUnknown` error in the `didFailWithError` function. Apple's documentation says that:

> If the location service is unable to retrieve a location right away, it reports a kCLErrorLocationUnknown error and keeps trying. In such a situation, you can simply ignore the error and wait for a new event.

So I assume that the location manager is still trying to get the location at this point?

Now when I use the iPhone simulator and purposely give it no location, it also returns this `LocationUnknown` error. How can I know that the location can definitely not be retrieved, as opposed to just ignoring the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation tells you, you have to keep trying. Actually, the location manager will do this for you. You ask it to start updating locations, and it just keeps sending you locations, of which the first one or two will *always* be "unknown". But usually, as the sensors warm up, you'll then start to get better and better location information. Typically you'll watch the time, so if you keep getting bad locations you can just time out after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

Comment: Ahh I see. So how long do you think is an appropriate time? I'm looking to get the location to an accuracy of 400m.

Comment: It's your app; you decide on the timeout. My example is here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift but the timeout is just a constant (and so is the desired accuracy) and you are free to plug in any values you think appropriate.